# Errors while adding Swift file to Objective-C iOS Library used in React Native project

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

I have an iOS react native project, which uses custom created iOS library written in Objective-C which serves as a bridge between shopify native ios sdk and react native. Currently I use v.2.x sdk written in Obj-C and need to update it to v.3.x which is written in Swift and cannot be imported into Obj-C project as it is using swift-specific features. So I try to replace my existing Objective-C class which serves as a bridge to RN with swift class, which would be exposed to RN and would call shopify methods. The problem is that as soon as I add swift file to my project things get broken. I receive strange error in foundation and others, like "unknown type namespace" in cstddef, "Could not build module Darwin" and others. Have you faced the same issues or maybe have an idea how it can fixed? It seems like Xcode tries to compile C libraries as Swift and as a result I get these errors.

[image]

Comment: If you would like to get a helpful answer sooner, you may want to try reproducing the problem in a very small, highly simplified project.  Then use that small example in a question, so people can better see the issue.  BTW, is C++ somehow involved here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, actually the project is very simple by itself, it only contains one Obj-C class which server a bridge between native API and React Native. I will try to make a new library from scratch written in swift and see if it works.
No, c++ is not involved. The errors I get are in Foundation and other native frameworks, they may be using c++